# WPF access controls in <ResourceDictionary>

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I am trying to access a button in a  .xaml file within a code behind file of my MainWindow.xaml . I Have tried to use x:Class in the  file but when I use it the button works but I get a lot of other errors. so I prefer not to use this method.

Is there any other ways to access controls in a template with a  from the mainWindows class.

the code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
                xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Avalon.Demo" x:Class="Bildbanken.MainWindow">
```

```
                        <!-- Taggarnas placering under bilderna (Left/ Top/ Right/ Bottom) -->
                        <Label Content="{Binding Type}" Padding="0,5,7,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Category}" Padding="7,0,0,0" />
                        <ListBox Name="ArtInfo" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="115px" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Artnr}"></TextBlock>
                                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="testbutton" Grid.Column="1">--</Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Could you please specify WHY are you trying to get reference to a button in a template? I may be wrong but in 99.9% it's a bad practice to do such things in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the contents of a datatemplate.  You can get the root element of the template like this:

```
UIElement templateRoot = listbox.ItemTemplate.LoadContent() as UIElement;
```

From there, you use the VisualTreeHelper to look for a Button control.

If you are just looking to handle the click of the button, utilizing the RoutedEvents of WPF is a better alternative.

```
AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click));
```

This will grab every button click, regardless of the source.  If you give the button a tag or something, you can test that to filter just those buttons you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a RoutedCommand which you can add via CommandBinding to you DataTemplate and to the button. That way you can handle the button click / command execute for example in the code behind and do not need find the button via the VisualTreeHelper (or my tipp would be SomeElement.TryFindResource("ButtonKey")).

Clear what I mean or did I missunderstand the thing you want to do with you button?

Answer (score 0):

First your make a .cs file, where you register your commands. This could be named MyCommandCollection.cs. In this class you define and register your RoutedCommand with:

```
   public static readonly RoutedCommand ButtonPressCommand= new RoutedCommand("ButtonPress", typeof(MyCommandCollection));
```

You define the Command in the UserControl or the Window you want to use it within e.g.

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
     <CommandBinding Command="Commands:MyCommandCollection.ButtonPressCommand" Execute="Execute_ButtonPressCommand" ... />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

In the code-behind of your UserControl / Window you implement the Execute / CanExecute methods of your command.

That way you can use it also in an ResourceDictionary, for example like that:

```
<Button Command="Commands:MyCommandCollection.ButtonPressCommand" />
```

Don't forget to also put the namespaces of your "MyCommandCollectionClass.cs" in the UserControl / Window and the ResourceDictionary, for example:

```
xmlns:Commands="clr-namespace:MyApp.SomeFolder.Commands"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself needing codebehind for the contents of a template, it's usually a good idea to move the template contents into a user control. (And it's often a good idea even when you don't need codebehind.)

This [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297195/wpf-passing-parameters-to-a-resourcedictionary/4297283#4297283) illustrates the technique. (The question may not seem relevant, but the answer happened to involve the same approach I'm advocating here. That example happens to use hierarchical templates, but it's just as applicable to normal ones.)

User controls offer two benefits here. First, they help avoid getting overly complicated Xaml files - it's easy for templates to dominate a Xaml file if you leave their bodies inline rather than separating them into their own files. Second, you can use codebehind easily.

That said, I agree with the various other answers here that advocate avoiding codebehind in the first place. (I don't quite agree with their specific solutions - I use the command-based approach, but I don't use `RoutedCommand` - I use a custom implementation of `ICommand` that follows a pattern typically called DelegatingCommand or RelayCommand.) But even then, I still almost define template bodies as user controls, just to simplify the Xaml.